# How to prevent form from submitting if email already exist in ASP.net MVC using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a registration form in asp.net mvc and i want to prevent that form from submission if that particular email already exist. I want to solve it using ajax, without using Remote Attribute. Below is the code. I have checked email availability using ajax but do not know how to prevent the form submission. If user presses on the submit button then only alert box should display is email already exist.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#txtUsername').blur(function(){
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:'/Home/CheckName',
data:"{'searchString':'"+ document.getElementById('txtUsername').value + "'}",
success : function(data)
{
if(data=="true")
{
alert("Username not Available");
}
else
{
alert("Username Available");
}
});
});
});


  HomeController.cs

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(User model)
{
try
{
db.AddToUsers(model);
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
return View("Index",model);
}
}
}


public JsonResult CheckName(string searchString)
{
var count=db.Users.Where(c=>c.User.Contains(searchString)).Count();
if(count>=1)
{
return Json(true);
}
else
{
return Json(false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a global variable, set it in your method, then upon clicking submit check the var.

add this global var:

```
 var _canSubmit = false;  //default

 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#txtUsername').blur(function(){
 $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/Home/CheckName',
    data:"{'searchString':'"+ document.getElementById('txtUsername').value + "'}",
    success : function(data)
    {
       if(data=="true")
       {
          _canSubmit = true;
          alert("Username not Available");
       }
       else
       {
          _canSubmit = false;
          alert("Username Available");
       }
    });
 });
 });
```

then upon click of the submit add this:

```
 javascript:if ( _canSubmit == false ) { return false } else{ return true; }
```